# Looking out a windows DNS configuration to server 2 domains

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008

Have a setup having 2 Active directory on different domain.Wanted to configure single DNS server to serve both domains .I have windows 2008 configured for DNS server & created  2 forward zone's on DNS server for each domain. Issue is whenever i do nslookup from the client configured for 2nd domain ,lookup points to first server .Please let me know what configuration is needed to achieve the above scenario sothat when i do nslookup for the clients from 1st domain should get resolved from 1st zone & 2nd from 2nd zone.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You should create a conditional forwarder on the two DCs so that:

DC1 - Domain name example.com
DC2 - Domain name example.org

On DC1 - Configure a conditional forwarder for example.org to DC2
On DC2 - Configure a conditional forwarder for example.com to DC1

Then you can use whichever DC you like as the DNS server for your clients and they will always resolve both domains correctly.